# Is there an easier way to run multiple altcoins in one service than operating each daemon?

Tags: trading, altcoin, altcoin-development

I am interested how to operate multiple currencies in one service like modern trading platforms do: Cryptsy(496 trading pairs), Bittrex (328 trading pairs), Poliniex(172 trading pairs).

The only way I see is to install all the daemons of each currency, but maybe there is some other more easy solution.